# Arraylist as property/global variable in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I have an arrayList created as property (accessible by all threadgroups)
after adding some values to this arraylist..using foreach loop to this arraylist i want to get maximum value from the arraylist and store it in a variable?
Someone pl help me with this

I am not able to iterate through that global(accessible by all threadgroups) arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter's [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) can only iterate [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), not properties so the options are in:

1. Either use [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with the number of loops equal to the number of items in the arraylist
2. Or convert the arraylist into JMeter Variables using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like this:

   ```
   def list = props.get('list')

   1.upto(list.size(), { index ->
       vars.put('var_' + index, list[index - 1])
   })
   ```

   it will generate the following JMeter Varibles

   ```
   var_1=first item of your list
   var_2=second item of your list
   etc
   ```

   and these variables could be used in the ForEach Controller normally